# Match commas with no white space before or after excluding thousands separators

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a comma surrounded by alpha characters with no space leading or trailing but to ignore if they are surrounded by numerals such as the thousands separator in a large number.

Below is what I have so far but the problem is that the Full Match returns the comma with the first character. `,v` in this example. However I just need the comma to be returned as the full match.
I have tried `(,)(?:[^\d\s])` and also `(,)(?:[^\d\s])\K` but with the `\K` the full match is empty.

I want to match the first and third line from this example but ignore the second and fourth:

```
uncased,vertical
80,000 btu
80,000,vertical
80,000, vertical
```

https://regex101.com/r/YH0Vd0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *regex ( using [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) )* should do it :

```
,(?=[^\d\s])
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oQ3Bjj/1)**

Comment: @Yamaha32088 You're Welcome :)